# Subclassing, protocols, and delegates - not calling

Tags: objective-c, delegates, protocols

I have 2 classes:

```
@protocol MainProtocol
-(void) method1;
@end

@interface ClassA : NSObject
@property id <MainProtocol> delegate;
@end
```

and

```
@protocol SubProtocol <MainProtocol>
-(void) method2
@end

@interface ClassB : ClassA
@end

@implementation ClassB

-(void) foo {
    [self.delegate method1]; // works fine
    [self.delegate method2]; // error
}

@end
```

I am not sure why I am unable to call `method2` with `self.delegate`.  Is it because `delegate` is declared in the parent class?  If so, how do I localize `delegate` in `ClassB`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `-[ClassB foo]`, `self.delegate` is declared as type `id<MainProtocol>` – that is, it conforms to MainProtocol, but not necessarily to SubProtocol. As such, ClassB instances aren't sure that `delegate` responds to `-method2`. You can redeclare `delegate` in ClassB as an object of type `id<SubProtocol>` if you want to send `-method2` to it.

Comment: That was it.  I didn't realized I was declaring delegate to conform only to that protocol.  Thanks for pointing out my obvious mistake :-/